# How to recognize a brand in a text with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been stuck for 2 days on this and I am sure it can be done with Elasticsearch. Any help would be really appreciated!

I receive products from various sources and I want to integrate them to my current inventory.

Products reach me in the form of text. They generally have a brand and a name:

```
1000 Stories Zinfandel Bourbon Barrel Aged
1000 Stories Gold Rush Red Blend Bourbon Barrel
1000 Stories Cabernet Bourbon Barrel Aged
^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   Brand              Product Name
```

But one can be missing or they can be mixed. That's why I want to recognize what is there and what is missing.

I generally already know the brands and products from my inventory. How can I get Elasticsearch to tell me which is what?

Ideally, I would get something like:

```
<brand>1000 Stories</brand> <name>Zinfandel Bourbon Barrel Aged</name>
<brand>1000 Stories</brand> <name>Gold Rush Red Blend Bourbon Barrel</name>
<brand>1000 Stories</brand> <name>Cabernet Bourbon Barrel Aged</name>
```

Though just recognizing the brand would already be a big step.

---

I was hoping to make it work with phrase suggestion, because it already includes the matches in the results. I have tried to map my brands and names with all those analyzers:

```rb
  settings: {
    analysis: {
      analyzer: {
        trigram: {
          type: "custom",
          tokenizer: "standard",
          filter: ["lowercase","shingle"]
        },
        reverse: {
          type: "custom",
          tokenizer: "standard",
          filter: ["lowercase","reverse"]
        },
        raw_analyzer: {
          tokenizer: "keyword",
          filter: [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      filter: {
        shingle: {
          type: "shingle",
          min_shingle_size: 2,
          max_shingle_size: 3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mappings: {
    product: {
      properties: {
        brand: {
          type: "text",
          fields: {
            trigram: {
              type: "text",
              analyzer: "trigram"
            },
            reverse: {
              type: "text",
              analyzer: "reverse"
            },
            raw: {
              type: "text",
              analyzer: "raw_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
```

And searched them with each analyzer:

```rb
      phrase_name_suggestion: {
        phrase: {
          field: 'name.trigram',
          max_errors: 0.99,
          size: 5,
          gram_size: 3,
          direct_generator: [
            {
              field: "name.trigram",
              suggest_mode: "always"
            },
            {
              field: "name.reverse",
              suggest_mode: "always",
              pre_filter: "reverse",
              post_filter: "reverse"
            }          ],
          highlight: {
            pre_tag: "<name>",
            post_tag: "</name>"
          }
        }
      },
      phrase_name_raw_suggestion: {
        phrase: {
          field: 'name.raw',
          max_errors: 0.99,
          size: 5,
          gram_size: 3,
          highlight: {
            pre_tag: "<name>",
            post_tag: "</name>"
          }
        }
      }
```

I am only getting random suggestions on the wrong terms, or no results at all. Like a term of a brand suggested for a term of a name, instead of just recognizing the brand.

Note in case it narrows the options: names are manually input, so I can get all variety of text: missing name, typos ("Sinfandel" for "Zinfandel"), abbreviations ("cab sauv" for "cabernet sauvignon"), ... That's a separate issue but if it can be included into this solution I'll happily take it.

I am running Elasticsearch 6.4.2. I can work with a more recent version if needed.

Comment: have a look https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp

Comment: @Lupanoide: thanks, I had not looked into ES ingest API yet or modules, looking at it now. I'm still hoping it can be done out of the box without extensions though.

Comment: for this solution you need an OpenNLP model . Then Elastic extract the entities. Named entities recognition. It is an elastic plugin and you need to download the NER models from sourceforge after installation.

To download the models, run the following under Linux and osx (this is in the bin directory of your Elasticsearch installation)

bin/ingest-opennlp/download-models